# Clicking on a link doesn't work, but copy-paste the link in browser works

Tags: url, outlook

I've created report a problem form for a website. So, whenever user experiences a problem, he/she can report a problem. They have to submit it using the google form. Some of the values like URL and browser details are fetched automatically in the form and user doesn't have to enter it manually. After each submission of the report, I get email notification of the forms values filled by that user in Outlook. I'm using Outlook Desktop App.

My Problem:
For one of the reports, what I'm facing is that when I click the URL, it doesn't work. If I copy paste the URL, it works fine.

What I tested so far:
I have tried to click the link in Outlook windows app, Outlook(web), gmail(web) and yahoo(web) and Outlook(Android App), but it's not working in either of them.

Please let me know if you have any idea why this happens. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened because the link had the double quotes in itself. So, whenever I clicked the link, it would only open the URL till first instance of double quotes is encountered.

Solution:
I need to encode the URL in order to behave properly

Answer (score 0):

After you copy/paste the original form code into a browser, the url will change and usually remove the "?usp=sf_link" (or similar) tail.  Try copying this url and it should work as a button or link.